# Token-based Authentication: Restricting Routes to Specific Users

Tags: jwt, token, restful-authentication

I have an express backend that implements JSON Web Token authentication. Once the user has provided the correct username and password a token is generated using a Secret.

Now let's say this user wants to delete a project of theirs, to do this a DELETE request is sent to programs/:programId. The API server uses the JWT middleware to verify if the token is valid, then the database is updated.

Basically my question is: how do I ensure that the user that is making the request is the owner of the project? If I can simply send a request to the correct route with **any** valid token and a valid body, what's to stop any user from sending malicious requests and removing/editing/accessing other user's data?

Does this have something to do with the JWT payload?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can handle this, and the exact solution you choose would depend on your architecture, whether or not you are using an API gateway, etc.

One approach to prevent a user from deleting someone else's project would be to change the delete API such that it also requires a user ID as one of the input parameters.  Assuming you made only this change, then your workflow would be something like this:

- user makes a request to the server with a JWT
- server attempts to unsign/open the JWT
- if successful, the server then checks the claims (e.g. expiry) to make sure the token is valid, and then extracts the username
- the server then routes the incoming `programId` from the request, along with the user ID from the JWT, to the deletion endpoint
- the content gets deleted

The key point above is that the server does *not* accept a user ID from the outside.  Rather, it is up to user to prove that he has a valid JWT, from which his user ID may be extracted.

Comment: Is the claim expiry something I have to do manually? I assumed that using a JWT library to decode/open the JWT would automatically return an error if the token has expired?

Comment: @chrisheseltine If you are not setting the `exp` (standard name for expiry claim) claim explicitly, then most likely your API would be doing that when your server creates and issues the JWT.  But yes, someone/something has to assign an expiry.